# ios8 local authentication framework

Tags: authentication, ios8, passwords, fingerprint, touch-id

In iPhone app i want to do authentication before opening a screen.
I want this authentication to be applied to this app only and shouldn’t’
interfere with phone level authentication.

I have included Local Authentication framework

In settings -> TouchID & passcode i have added my fingerprint
Initially i didn’t’ enable anything in the TouchID & passcode screen
I have got the following error when i tried the evaluatePolicy

Error Domain=com.apple.LocalAuthentication Code=-5 
"Passcode not set." UserInfo=0x1742716c0

Turned on the passcode in TouchID & passcode screen.
Now it detects my fingerprint and opens the next screen.
But if the phone locks it asks for the passcode to unlock the phone.
As i mentioned i want the authentication to be applied to app level only.

Please let me know how we can do the authentication is app level only.

```
   LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];

[context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
        localizedReason:@“prove yourself ?”
                  reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

                      if (error) {

                          return;
                      }

                      if (success) {
                          NSLog(@"you are the iPhone owner");

                          open the next screen

                      } else {

                      }

                  }];
```

The same happens when i enable iPhone unlock in TouchID & passcode screen

[image]

Comment: Do you have "Use Touch ID for iPhone Unlock" turned on in Settings?

Comment: Yes. I mentioned it at the end.

Comment: I had this problem and I fixed by enable pass code settings on the iPhone